# best practices for uploading many files to live server while updating database

Tags: bash, ftp

I have roughly 200 files that I need to push to our live server after business hours.  In addition to this push I have a few database updates that I need to run in conjunction with this roll out.

What has been done in the past on this system is to create a directory on the server of the updated files and create a cron script to copy those files to overwrite their previous versions on the server.  And then executing the calls to the database.

Here are the problems I am trying to work around:

1) There is no staging server.

2) There is no easy way to push from our version control (svn) to our live server

3) There are a lot of files and the directory structure is deep so setting up a copy of the directories to be copied over on the server seems precarious and time consuming.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: short of installing a true combined revision/build/deploy system, AND depending on how often you're going to need to do this AND how much the list of files will change, I would make a shell script that loops on ftp using a cfg file with just 2 entries per line, i.e. `/src/path/file.txt remoteHost:/alt/path/blah/blah/`. You could also use that file to drive a 2nd pass that compares the file entries (confirming that new file got copied). Lots of other things come to mind, but not knowing the specifics, it would be hard to opinionate further ;-) ... Good luck!

Comment: Hm, database updates. Hopefully you know where there is risk of a database update affecting one of the files OR visea-versa. Is there a possibility that you have a live db accepting changes while you're changing files underneath? Could be a recipe for disaster. ----- Are you running backups before starting all of this? Have you ever tried to restore a backup and prove they work? I've seen where  "enterprise grade backup" didn't work as advertized. More testing and planning seem likely for you my friend. Like they say at the dentists, Only spend time flossing teeth you want to keep. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done similar things in the past is to have a cron job run a script an administrative machine that:

1) checks out the files I need on my production server on some sort of staging machine
2) rsync's the files onto the server
3) runs a post-rsync script on the server (say via ssh'ing to the server)

However, you specify that you have no ability to use a staging machine, by which I assume you mean that you have no administrative machine at all, and that you cannot check out your repository on the server either. That makes doing this cleanly far harder. Are you sure you can't at least use your workstation or some similar box as an administrative or staging machine here?